# ActionScript3 - How to remove only after the Tween move is over

Tags: actionscript-3

I want the last statement `removeChild(dropBall1);` in this script, to be executed only after the Tween move is over. How do I do that? right now as it is, it gets removed right away.

```
function onClick10f1(e: MouseEvent) {

addChild(dropBall1)
removeChild(bigBall1)
dropBall1.x = 356.10;
dropBall1.y = 28;
var bigBDrop1: Tween = new Tween(dropBall1, "y", Regular.easeIn, 28, 156, 1, true);
removeChild(dropBall1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is to make use of the [`TweenEvent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/TweenEvent.html) class.

Basically, with TweenEvents, you can choose what to do, during the lifecycle of a tween. It is important to note that variable scoping becomes an issue with listeners. It's been a long while since I've used the Tween and TweenEvent class, so you may need to restructure the event handler function to have access to the `dropBall1` variable as I don't remember if the function will have access to it.

Try this:

```
function onClick10f1(e:MouseEvent) {

    addChild(dropBall1);
    removeChild(bigBall1);
    dropBall1.x = 356.10;
    dropBall1.y = 28;
    var bigBDrop1:Tween = new Tween(dropBall1, "y", Regular.easeIn, 28, 156, 1, true);

    bigBDrop1.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onFinish);

}

function onFinish(e:TweenEvent) {
    removeChild(dropBall1);
}
```

And also be sure to add the necessary import statement for the TweenEvent class:

```
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
```

Comment: When trying your suggestions I get error: " Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: TweenEvent." and I do have the "import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;"

Comment: Correction I didn't have the import. it works now. Thanx

Comment: this provides a solution to PO question but does it by providing a flawed code which will only confuse the PO more. This code can't work correctly because the object 'bigBDrop1' is a local variable and will be eventually GC causing the tween to just stop at random time (or not if it can complete before GC). Fix that code so that bigBDrop1 can't get GC.

Answer (score 0):

The `Tween` object dispatches an `Event` (more precisely: a TweenEvent) of type `TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH`